# Eclipse Main program Launch error

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven

I have a maven project (Swing client), inside which i have a class file called ClientContainerLauncher, the main method is as below,

```
/**
 * The main to launch a client CDI container from the command line.
 *
 * @param args Command line arguments.
 * @throws Exception If the client CDI container fails to launch.
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClientContainerLauncher launcher = new ClientContainerLauncher();
    launcher.launch();
}
```

When i launch debug/run i am getting below error,

[image]

generated-configuration is one of my other maven project, but the current project has no dependency with generated-configuration project but throws this error. Even after adding it as dependency(generated-configuration) project also i am getting the same error.

I have tried to take maven update, clean project and debug/run, but nothings works. How do i solve it. Help me.

Comment: Are generated-configuration and your Swing client modules of the same Maven project or are they totally unrelated?

Comment: They are 2 different maven projects

Comment: Just wondering: did you happen to create your Swing project by copying elements of generated-configuration? If so, Eclipse may have stored undesired references in the settings, which could explain the cause. I am not sure of this, since closing generated-configuration solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse sometimes do weird things with Maven projects. Here are a few leads:

- If your current project and generated-configuration are totally unrelated (not even as modules of a same Maven parent), and if you don't need generated-configuration, just close that project for now (right click on the project `> Close project`).
- You can also use `Maven > update`: this tells the m2eclipse plugin to update the Eclipse project configuration based on the pom.xml files. You could try it on `generated-configuration` (actually, it is a good habit to use it every time you make important changes to a pom).
- If you do need it, try to install it to your local repo by using `Run as > Maven install`.

  - If the projects are related, I would recommend running it on the parent.
  - If not, just run it on `generated-configuration` and optionnally on your current project.

I am not sure any of these will help but it is the best I can propose with the current information.

Comment: Closing the generated-configuration and starting the main does helped. Thank You Chop

Comment: Do you know how to start without closing the generated-configuration project? because i need this project open for some other service.

Comment: @Arasu Have you tried my other suggestions (I just added one I did not think of earlier)? If none of that works, my only other idea without seeing your Eclipse would be to unaccept my answer (as it did not solve your problem) so that other ideas may pop up. :)

Comment: I tried installing the application using mvn install but still the error pops out. I cannot run the application inside generated-configuration, since i don't have permission to run there.